# Performance of jquery filter()

Tags: jquery

I have a table like -

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>fruit1</td>
        <td>apple</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fruit2</td>
        <td>orange</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fruit3</td>
        <td>mango</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fruit4</td>
        <td>grape</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fruit5</td>
        <td>tomato</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fruit6</td>
        <td>kiwi</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fruit7</td>
        <td>litchi</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fruit8</td>
        <td>avocado</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fruit9</td>
        <td>papaya</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to filter this table based on the fruit number present in the first column and store it in a variable. So I've written `jquery` as -

```
var data = $('#myTable tr').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find('td:first').text() === 'fruit1';
})[0];
```

This code works fine, but my concern is that this seems very complicated and might make the UI very slow. Is there any better way, performance-wise, to do the same?

Comment: You could use `:contains`, but that only ensures the value you search for is *within* the text of the element, not that it matches exactly as your `filter()` does. Personally, I'd say what you have is fine. If you're that concerned with performance then jQuery is not what you should be using.

Comment: I think you are worrying too early.

Comment: are you using IE ?

Comment: When you run the code yourself, does it make the UI very slow?

Comment: My concern is that the actual table is having around 1 MB of data. Almost at all times, this piece of code will return a single unique row. So I was wondering whether there's a better way of doing this?